# When do permutations commute?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

When do two permutations commute?

How do you find out something like how many permutations in $S_7$ commute with $(12)(345)$?

Comment: Conjugate permutations hardly ever commute.

Comment: $ ab = ba \iff b = a^{-1}ba $  ?

Comment: I second what you just wrote: $b$ commutes with $a$ if and only if the conjugate of $b$ with respect to $a$ is $b$ itself.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: Aah, I see I've misunderstood the meaning of conjugate.  What is the criteria for when permutations commute then?

Comment: The question is a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245990/find-all-permutations-that-commute-with-omega-1-9-7-10-12-2-54-113-6-8).

Comment: Here is a hint towards the answer. Given a cycle $\sigma=(i_1\ i_2\dots i_k)$, its conjugate $\pi\sigma\pi^{-1}=(\pi(i_1)\ \pi(i_2)\dots \pi(i_k))$. In other words, conjugation by $\pi$ permutes the positions and values of $\alpha$ according to $\pi$.

Answer (score 5):

Not true at all.  For example, the cycles $(1,2,3)$ and $(2,3,4)$ have the same cycle structure but do not commute.

Comment: In support of this: $P_{12}P_{23}\ne P_{23}P_{12}$ although both elements have the same cycle structure.

Answer (score 2):

The answer below is **incorrect** as stated and needs an edit, please see discussion below. And please don't upvote this, it's bad enough that this answer has gotten a bounty.

---

In your case (and in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245990/find-all-permutations-that-commute-with-omega-1-9-7-10-12-2-54-113-6-8) earlier question), all cycles have different lengths, but in general, a permutation may have some equal length cycles in its disjoint cycle decomposition. Permutations $\sigma$ and $\pi$ commute when $\pi$

- permutes elements within disjoint cycles of $\sigma$, and/or
- permutes the *sets* of elements in equal length disjoint cycles of $\sigma$.

Klein 4-group is the smallest nontrivial example of the second action. E.g. $(12)(34)$ commutes with $(13)(24)$ because $(13)(24)$ maps the set $\{1,2\}$ onto set $\{3,4\}$ and vice versa.

Comment: is this a necessary and sufficient condition for two permutation to commute? Thank you.

Comment: It’s easier to think of the conditions above as those for $\pi\sigma\pi^{-1}=\sigma$. Also $\sigma: i\mapsto j$ if and only if $\pi\sigma\pi^{-1}: \pi(i)\mapsto\pi(j)$. So, yes, the above conditions are necessary and sufficient for $\pi\sigma\pi^{-1}=\sigma$.

Comment: Thank a lot for the clarification :)

Comment: I have a doubt. please clarify. a = (124)(356) permutes elements within the cycle b = (123456). ie. It sends 1,2,3,4,5,6 to 1,2,3,4,5,6 . but these two cycles are not commuting. So can you please explain me your term "permutes elements within disjoint cycles of $\sigma$"?. Thank a lot.

Comment: You’re right, this doesn’t quite work as desired. I think I meant it to be in a way that preserves the cycles, i.e. for $(123456)$, that would be e.g. $(135)(246)$ or $(14)(25)(36)$. Those are both powers of $(123456)$, so I think this part can be made even more precise.

Comment: Thanks. Also can you please made it precise, that would be very helpful for later visitors like me :) .